# On linux how can make a list of files that are owned by a particular owner and then fix the group and owner?

Tags: linux, redhat, find

I have a deep and complex file system where some files have been accidently written by root. I want to change the ownership of those files back to the original owner in one go.

I am playing with commands like:

```
find /folder -type f | xargs ls -l | grep "root root"
```

but there is a lot of garbage coming out too.

I want to make a list first and then change only the files in that list after confirmation.

Answer (score 9):

```
find /folder -type -f -uid 0
```

will find all files under the directory owned by root, `-user root` would also work, naturally.

If all files below `/folder` should be owned by the same user/group, you could simply do an recursive `chown`:

```
chown -R user:group /folder
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
find /folder -uid 0 >/tmp/root.files
```

to get a list of files owned by root. Once you have reviewed the list you could use

```
while read file 
do
    chown user:group "$file"

done </tmp/root.files
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the other answers use `find` with either `-uid 0` or `-user root` to find files belonging to root. Then use the `-exec`action:

`find /folder -type f -uid 0 -exec chown root:root {} \;`